# MediaPlayer.seekTo() doesn't work with audio stream

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app, that is streaming music from an online source, using standard Android MediaPlayer.
I want to add a feature to pause stream and after a while continue listening it in live.

Standard Mediplayer.pause() and MediaPlayer.start() don't help. It starts music from the moment, when I pause the stream. I was trying to use MediaPlayer.seekTo() with different values, but it seems that it doesn't work with live stream.

That's an error I get:

`W/MediaPlayerNative: Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable.`

So is it even possible to do, using MediaPlayer?

Comment: MediaPlayer is not design to use live streaming, it uses buffering while the user pause a live stream, the client might still be buffering content in the background. When you play again, it plays from the buffered content. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer is more  advanced streaming capabilities than the built-in MediaPlayer. bit it not design for live stream as well